# PL/SQL Chinese garbled in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

**My oracle version is 11g,installing on linux. Client is xp.**

Now,By PL/SQL to query data and the chinese grabled; like this(Field Name):
[image]

In pl/sql execute command:" select userenv('language') from dual;"  and show

> SIMPLIFIED CHINESE_CHINA.AL32UTF8(I think it is Server-side character set)

So I look at the Windows xp registry: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE->SOFTWARE->Oracle->NLS_LANG.
It show:

> SIMPLIFIED CHINESE_CHINA.ZHS16GBK （I think it is Client-side character set）

I changed it to

> SIMPLIFIED CHINESE_CHINA.AL32UTF8

But the Chinese are still garbled.

And,This "NAME" field should actually show :  "北京市".

I execute command:

`select dump(name,1016) from MN_C11_SM_S31 where objectid=1;`

and show:[image]

Does that mean that the data itself is stored is incorrect?
How should I do?

Supplementary：Just,I used C# code to parse this string by UTF-8:"e58c97e4baace5b882".

and it show: "北京市".I think this proves the data itself is not wrong.

Comment: Now maybe you can post the image, you have more than 15 reps!

Comment: What is the database character set?  Have you verified that the data is being correctly stored in the database using the `dump` command to look at the actual binary data?  What application are you using to view the data on the client?  Do you see the correct results when you use an inherently Unicode application like SQL Developer?

Comment: OK I have uploaded the pictures!

Comment: Have you tried querying this out with another application (looks like you're using sqlplus -- try oracle sql developer,toad, or whatever you have on your machine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be careful. 
SQLplus and OracleSqlDeveloper might actually display Chinese characters incorrectly.
And you need to take an nvarchar (utf8) field for a chinese string.

Try using a C# Windows application to input, insert and display data, it uses unicode internally, so you can at least rule out that bug source. Don't use a console application for display, console applications can't display Unicode characters correctly.

Then, you need to store your string in an nvarchar field (not varchar), and use a parameter of type nvarchar, when you insert your string.

```
INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE (newname)
VALUES (:UnicodeString)

command.Parameters.Add (":UnicodeString", OracleType.NVarChar).Value = stringToSave;
```

Comment: You don't need to use NVARCHAR2 if the database character set natively supports unicode characters (for instance AL32UTF8, as seems to be the case here).

Comment: @Vincent Malgrat: Just the question is whether the application will then feed you an ansi-string or an AL32UTF8 string. Besides, it's generally not very wise to use varchar and change the codepage on  the server AND the client, when you use non-ASCII characters.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using a unicode character set as your primary database character set, such as AL32UTF8. In this case you can use VARCHAR2 to store chinese characters, you don't need to use NVARCHAR2.